# How to install Google Play Store in Coby MID1060 without rooting?

Tags: google-play-store, coby-kyros

It seems every tutorial that I see needs to root the tablet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short answer:

You can't.

#### Explanation

The tutorials are correct about that: It's impossible without root -- as the *Playstore* app needs to be made a *System App* (i.e. must be installed in `/system` initially), or it won't work. The reason behind it is the permission system: certain permissions are only granted to system apps, and the *Playstore* app needs at least one of them.